# How to set table level privileges in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, privileges

I am trying to revoke select privilege from a particular table from a MySQL DB.
Database level restriction is working but table level is not.

When I write "show grants"
This is what I get :

```
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'rachit'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test123`.* TO 'rachit'@'localhost'                                                   |
| GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `test123`.`names123` TO 'rachit'@'localhost'
```

As you can see above I want to

revoke select privilege from rachit user on 'names123' table of 'test123' database, but SELECT is working.

I have attached a screenshot below for better understanding.
https://ibb.co/GRtjXX7

Answer (score 0):

If you `GRANT ALL ON test123.*  TO 'rachit'@'localhost'` you cannot remove one table by running `REVOKE ALL ON test123.* TO 'rachit'@'localhost'`.

some DBMS systems specifically `DENY` option for specifically denying access to specific table but this is not the case for mysql.

you may consider to write script and give access to each table one by one

Answer (score 0):

Discussion:

If it wasn't specifically `GRANTed`, it can't be `REVOKEd`.  This is an unfortunate side effect of the not-so-user-friendly Grant/Revoke syntax and implementation.

You can use a `SELECT` against `information_schema.TABLES` to automate the discovery of all the other tables.  And have the `SELECT` build the desired `GRANTs`.

Possible workaround:

Another approach to your particular problem is to move that one table to a different *database*.  Then `GRANT` different permissions to that db.